# For two sets of points find the plane about which they are reflected

Tags: linear-algebra

For two sets of points in vector-3 space that are mirrored transformations of each other about a given plane that doesn't go through the origin. And where the reflection matrix is not known. How could one calculate the normal and the origin of the said plane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the plane is a reflection plane that means it has to be perpendicular to the line connecting the two points. This means that a normal vector would be $v - v'$ where the $v$ and $v'$ are the two points. I'm not sure what you mean by the origin of a plane but the midpoint, $(v + v')/2$, between $v$ and $v'$ would have to be in the plane. A plane is uniquely described by a normal vector and a point in the plane so this would describe the reflection plane. Let $n = v - v'$ and $r_0 = (v + v')/2$, a point $w$ is in the reflection plane if and only if $n \cdot (w - r_0) = 0$.